# How to remove specific rows when a condition is fulfilled?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to remove/filter out some specific rows when it meets the condition of the two columns if not the column `EP` is flagged as `1`. What is the specific code for this?
For example: in the dataframe `df_NC` when the column "Population_type" (binary type) is equal to `1` and the column `NC` (binary type) is equal to `0`  remove the rows when this condition is satisfied, else flag `EP` as `1`

```
df_ep <- df_NC %>% mutate(EP= case_when(
 df_NC$Population_Type == 1 & df_NC$NC == 0 ~ 1,
 TRUE ~ 0
))
```

Comment: Try `df_NC[df_NC$Population_type != 1 & df_NC$NC != 0,]`

Comment: In this case, its removing all the rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code I'm assuming you are using `dplyr` package. A couple of mistakes there.

- You don't need to use the base notation like `df_NC$NC` inside `dplyr` functions, just use the name of the variable.
- I don't see a reason create the column `EP` if you are filtering one of the values (`0`/`FALSE`).

```r
df_NC %>%
  mutate(EC = if_else(Population_Type == 1 & NC == 0, 1, 0)) %>%
  filter(EC == 1)

# Or shorter, considering my second point
df_NC %>%
  filter(Population_Type == 1, NC == 0) # Equivalent to EC == 1
```

Also, try to use boolean (`TRUE`/`FALSE`) instead of integer `1`/`0` to work with "binary" data type.

Comment: thanks @Gabriel Silva and the reason to create the column **EP** is for the reason I am going to use the flagged value for later analysis